# Quantized momentum in compactified direction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, momentum, compactification

I'm reading [Szabo's book](https://books.google.be/books/about/An_Introduction_to_String_Theory_and_D_b.html?id=MAdqDQAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y). Here is exercise 6.1. :

> A relativistic particle of mass $m$ and charge $q$ in $d$ Euclidean
> spacetime dimensions propagates in a background electromagnetic vector
> potential $A_µ$ according to the action
> $$S[X,\dot{X}] = \int d\tau \left( \frac{m}{2}\dot{X}^2-iq\dot{X}^\mu A_\mu \right).$$
> Show that if the $d$-th direction is compactiﬁed on a circle of radius $R$, then a constant gauge ﬁeld $A_\mu = −\delta_{\mu,d} \theta/2\pi R$ momentum induces a fractional canonical momentum
> $$p^d = \frac{n}{R}+\frac{q\theta}{2\pi R}.$$

I have trouble solving this exercise. What is the main idea?